# htlatex with tcolorbox ignoriing left whitespace inside box

Tags: tcolorbox, tex4ht, make4ht

I am using the tcolorbox package and I need to produce html output together with pdf output. When I use tcolorbox with pdflatex it works fine and produces a nice box with space on either side. Wnen I use htlatex (make4ht mwe.tex) it ignores the space on the left. Is this a bug in htlatex? Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

Minimal working example to produce image:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Here is an example.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Example 1]
The should display as a nice box with some white space on the left and the right. 
It works fine with latex2pdf but when I use it with htlatex (make4ht) it ignores the space on the left.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: produced by make4ht mws.tex]
[image: produced by pdflatex mws.tex]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\def\calc:tcbpadding#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr \kvtcb@boxsep+#1\relax px}
\pend:def\a:tcolorbox{\Css{\#\:tcbcolid\space div{
  padding-top:\calc:tcbpadding{\kvtcb@top};
  padding-bottom:\calc:tcbpadding{\kvtcb@bottom};
  padding-left:\calc:tcbpadding{\kvtcb@leftupper};
  padding-right:\calc:tcbpadding{\kvtcb@rightupper};
}}}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It uses the dimensions used by Tcolorbox for CSS padding. To illustrate it, I've added few more boxes to your example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Here is an example.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Example 1]
The should display as a nice box with some white space on the left and the right. 
It works fine with latex2pdf but when I use it with htlatex (make4ht) it ignores the space on the left.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Example 2, boxsep=1em]
The should display as a nice box with some white space on the left and the right. 
It works fine with latex2pdf but when I use it with htlatex (make4ht) it ignores the space on the left.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Example 3, left=2cm]
The should display as a nice box with some white space on the left and the right. 
It works fine with latex2pdf but when I use it with htlatex (make4ht) it ignores the space on the left.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer. It works perfectly. thank you.

Comment: @user12833 that's good to hear. I've updated TeX4ht sources, so it should work soon out of the box in TeX Live.